# Laravel Cache: "Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed"

Tags: laravel

I am trying to Cache a collection of models along with a relation. However, this is returning an error.

> Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed

```
public static function cachedFaq()
{
    return Cache::remember('faq', 60 * 24 * 7, function () {
        return self::with(['articles'])
            ->whereHas('parent', function ($query) {
                $query->where('slug', 'faq');
            })
            ->get();
    });
}
```

When I omit the relation by removing `with(['articles'])`, it works. It also works when applying `toArray()` after the `get()`.

Why is it not possible returning a relationship like this?

Relations:

```
public function articles()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Article::class, 'category_id');
}

public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(ArticleCategory::class, 'parent_id');
}
```

Comment: Laravel's caching library serializes your results, however, `Closures` cannot be serialized, as stated from the error. The code you posted looks fine to me, can you provide some more details? what does `articles`, and `parent` look like?

Comment: I have updated my question to include the relationships. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for why I was getting this was that I was overriding the `__construct()`-method in of the Models.